# Call a shell script on a button press & kill it after pressed again

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, gpio

I can't seem to figure out how to kill a script in python after it's called. Any ideas?

"Party.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
input = GPIO.input(11)
import time
import os
#initialise a previous input variable
prev_input = 1
party = 0
while True:
  #take a reading
  input = GPIO.input(11)
  #if the last reading was low and this one high, print
  if ((not prev_input) and input):
    if (party ==  0):
        os.system("./home/tim/bin/dalitest")
        party = 1
    elif (party == 1):
        #Kill the script
        party = 0
    time.sleep(2)
  #update previous input
  prev_input = input
  #slight pause to debounce
  time.sleep(0.05)
```

A different python script is called here os.system("./home/tim/bin/dalitest")
How do I kill the other Python script within the main one?

Comment: use subprocess and kill the process

Comment: Not sure about python in particular, but `system` is usually a blocking function: by the time it returns, the child process should already be dead an reaped (=not a zombie).

Comment: @PSkocik Oh, the "dalitest" is a forever loop....

Comment: Then, with a standard `system` implementation, it wouldn't ever return. You need something from the os.spawn* family (equivalent to running a bash command with an ampersand at the end), which can return immediately and give you a pid you can use to kill the child. Don't forget to wait on the child then to prevent zombies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

**Spawning**

```
#spawn by path + return immediately  and get pid
pid = os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "./home/tim/bin/dalitest")
```

**Killing**

```
#kill pid
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

#wait for pid to release it back to the system
#this will block until the child is dead
os.waitpid(pid,0)
```